# More detailed list view on android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I'm trying to design a page for my app that will be a list of places. I need each list entry to have a picture, text below, short description, and some other info, address

The list view fragment examples that I've seen simply have one or two lines  which won't really do what I need it to... where do go from here? I'm not sure what to search for, nothing useful has come up so far..

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to make a custom `ArrayAdapter`.

Check out some of these examples:

[Android Custom Listview with Image and Text using ArrayAdapter](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)

[Android Custom ListView with Images and Text – Example](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)

[Customizing Android ListView Items with Custom ArrayAdapter](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)